# ARTIFACTORY: How to copy/move artifacts between different projects?

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to copy/move a single package from one project to another project. There is an official doco with the same title as this [here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-copy-move-artifacts-between-different-projects/), but it only demos copying/moving entire repo or copying a folder in a repo, not a file. Any help with this?

This works for the entire repo:

```
curl -XPOST -u username:password "https://ART_HOST/artifactory/api/copy/project1-repo1?to=project2-repo2"
```

Now I want it to work in this way:

```
curl -XPOST -u username:password "https://ART_HOST/artifactory/api/copy/project1-repo1/file1?to=project2-repo2/file2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still copy/move a specific artifact between projects considering you are the admin using this [copy REST API](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/copy-item) or [move REST API](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/move-item) using the correct repository key as below

```
curl -uadmin -XPOST https://myartiafctory.jfrog.com/artifactory/api/copy/SOURCE-REPO-KEY/PATH-OF-THE-FILE?to=TARGET-REPO-KEY
```

if successful, you will get the below output,

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "level": "INFO",
      "message": "copying source-repo:file-path to target-repo: completed successfully, 1 artifacts and 0 folders were copied"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if we have DEVELOPER access, not ADMIN?